# url for accounts/profile in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-1.11

I'm using Django 1.11 and new to it.

I'm using default login and logout functions.

When I login, it redirects to `accounts/profile` and then generates error as

```
Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^ ^login/$ [name='login']
^ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
^ ^password_change/$ [name='password_change']
^ ^password_change/done/$ [name='password_change_done']
^ ^password_reset/$ [name='password_reset']
^ ^password_reset/done/$ [name='password_reset_done']
^ ^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$ [name='password_reset_confirm']
^ ^reset/done/$ [name='password_reset_complete']
^ ^$ [name='home']
^pages/
^search/
^admin/

The current path, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.
```

**Is `accounts` built-in function in Django?**

**If it is, how to access url to `accounts` app? If no, why it is there?**

> Edit 2 : url pattern from `myapp.urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url('^', include('pages.urls')),
    url(r'^pages/', include('pages.urls')),
    url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: it would help to see your code...and your urlpatterns

Comment: see `Edit 2` in question. everthing is working fine, my question is about `accounts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, successful login in Django redirects to:

- URL passed as `?next=` parameter in the URL, or
- URL specified as `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` otherwise.

Relevant code: [`LoginView.get_success_url()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L92)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this and I have already set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` I want to create a page of logged in user profile and I think it can be easily achieved if `accounts` is build-in app

Comment: No, there's no built-in app `accounts`, there's only `django.contrib.auth`.

Answer (score 0):

The url accounts, normally comes with the package `django-registration`. For my case, it is implemented as `url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),`. From there the redirect works. i.e. accounts/login, accounts/register etc. See the [documentation](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/quickstart.html)